# Div page-breaking css

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I need to print an HTML page where all divs are't "pagebroken", without *page-break-after:always*, in order to show different short divs in the same page especially to avoid blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would do the trick.

`@media print {
    div {page-break-after: avoid;}
}`

Comment: thank you but it seems that page-break-after works only with table, list...

Comment: Hmm, it should work with `div` with `display:block;`. By chance is there an absolute positioning happening? That I know does mess with things.